# How does '#include' actually work in c++?

Tags: c++, include, preprocessor, extern

Suppose that I have 2 files: header.h and main.cpp (they are all in the same folder)
-header.h

```
int x;
```

-main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include<iostream>
extern int x;
int main(){
  x=1;
  std::cout<<x;
}
```

-Everything I know about the directive '#include' is that it replaces the content of the file included where we use #inlcude, but there is a conflict, typically that is the above code:
+If #include actually copy everything in the header file, perhaps we can use the variable 'x' normally without declaring it with 'extern' keyword because 'extern' indicates that this variable is declared in another file.This means #include doesn't actually do something like Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V\n
I still wonder this problem

I just want a persuasive answer

Comment: I'm not sure what the example is intended to prove. Your understanding is correct. The `#include "header.h"` is replaces with the contents of header.h resulting in a file [that looks (ignoring iostream) like this](https://godbolt.org/z/cGGvzhG43). There is only one `x` defined, `int x;`. There are two declarations, `int x;`, and `extern int x;`, but that's fine since they are effectively identical. There is no problem here. Perhaps the problem is with your understanding of `extern`?

Comment: Although the code works in this particular case (including the header in only one file), you normally want to reverse the situation, so the header would have `extern int x;` and exactly one .cpp file would have `int x;`. But yes, `#include` just fills in the contents of the header in place of the `#include` directive.

Comment: `extern int x;` doesn't "indicates that this variable is declared in another file". It declares that entity `x` of type `int` is having global linkage.  Even though it got no effect for global functions and variables declared in same compilation unit, it is legal to have both extern declaration and actual definition in same scope. A file with all included files is a compilation unit. `extern` is a declaration, so one definition rule isn't broken here.

Comment: In some cases the idea of `#include`being replaced by Copy&pasted the file contents sufficient to understand what's happending. However there are cases where this breaks down: If the `#include` is excluded by the preprocessor via `#if` (and similar), the `#include` is simply ignored. Furthermore `#include`s in an included file are resolved with respect to the location of the included file, not with respect to the location of the including file.

Comment: *I just want a persuasive answer* See [preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that `#include` is just a simple textual substitution, nothing more.  So your `main.cpp` expands to this:

```
int x;

*contents of iostream.h inserted here*

extern int x;
int main(){
  x=1;
  std::cout<<x;
}
```

The difference between `int x` and `extern int x` is that the former **defines storage**. The latter just **declares** the variable.  `extern` doesn't necessarily mean storage is in another file, it's simply telling the compiler, "if you encounter a symbol named x after this line, just assume it's an integer defined elsewhere".

Or put it another way, `int x` formally defines the variable including its storage and location. And `extern int x` just declares it. You can have as many declarations as you want for a symbol, but you need exactly one definition for it.

In general, you don't declare storage or define variables in headers. You put the `extern int x` in the header so you can share that variable in all the source files that include your header.  Than you have one specific file with the global storage and definition of `int x`.

Better:

**header.h**

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

extern int x;

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int x;

int main(){
  x=1;
  std::cout<<x;
}
```

Interestingly enough for the above example, you don't actually need to include `header.h` in main.cpp since you already got `x` defined (and implicitly declared) near the top of the source file.

But if you structured your code such that main was using `x` without the definition, then the header serves the program better. In general, it's a good idea for the source file providing function implementations and global variable storage to include it's own header file - it helps detect conflicts and between definition and declaration better. For example, if `header.h` declared x as a float, you'd get a huge warning about it being referenced as an int in `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main(){
  x=1;            // wouldn't work if header.h was missing
  std::cout<<x;
}

int x; // storage defined after the variable was already declared and used
```